# .htaccess file in subdomain doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

I've setup a folder on my server and I'm trying to write a new .htaccess file.
But it doesn't work. Perhaps the root dir .htaccess file over rules it.

Here is a simple code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule horse.htm zebra.htm
```

But this url "http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/horse.htm" goes to my wordpress instead of "http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/zebra.htm"

Why doesn't my .htaccess file work?

Comment: Where is your htaccess file? In `/demo/pwnzuck/`? Or is it mixed together with the wordpress reiwrte rules?

Comment: `But this url "http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/pwnzuck/horse.htm" goes to my wordpress instead of...` Where in your Wordpress, how is the final URL?

Comment: Where in the Wordpress space is my question, because your rule might be in conflict with the WP redirection process (permalinks setting), which, by the way, it is not done in .htaccess file. If that's the case, you won't achieve much with rewrite rules, except breaking the permalinks strategy.

Comment: My wordpress .htaccess is in root.
I'm doing all these experiments in a new folder pwnzuck which is under a demo folder. The new .htaccess file is in the pwnzuck folder
@faa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} horse\.htm   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !zebra\.htm  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  demo/pwnzuck/zebra.htm [R=301,L]
```

#### UPDATE

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /pwnzuck/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php         [NC]
RewriteRule .*  demo/pwnzuck/index.php?url=%1  [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/pwnzuck/val1`

To:

`http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/pwnzuck/index.php?url=val1`

For a permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

Comment: In your rules RewriteBase and the path in the substitution URL were missing. When `RewriteBase` is set to `/`, the prefix automatically prepended to the substitution URL is also `/`, therefore depends only on the path the location of the file the incoming URL is mapped to. If the file is now `index.php`, the rule-set must be modified accordingly and the first question is ¿where in the incoming URl is the parameter xyz?

Comment: Updated my answer. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it, selecting the check mark in the upper left of this answer.

Comment: I tried the new code, it works like charm :) thank you.
One last thing, can it accept urls? Currently if I have a url like http://google.com/pollo instead of XYZ it shows me only 'pollos'.
If I can get the entire part http://google.com/pollos that'd be great!

Comment: Replace `([^/]+)` with this `(.*)` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^horse.htm$ zebra.htm
```

Comment: nope. it didn't work.
the statement which I had initially used was a broad one. it is supposed to work irrespective of what comes before or after horse.htm

Comment: I picked it up from here - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: Is your webhosting on Godaddy? They have a weird thing setup and you need an extra couple of lines to make mod rewrite work the right way.

Comment: I'm on hostgator. The wordpress .htaccess rewrite rules are working fine.